# How to configure Apache CXF + WSS4J to prevent token from expiring?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, webclient, wss4j

I am using Apache CXF with wss4j to create a client for a webservice which uses Username token based authentication.

What I want to do is to authenticate the connection to the webservice only once since the process is a little slow(in order to use it every time the user whats to use that webservice functionality).

The problem that I ran into is that the UsernameToken expires if it is not used for a period of time.

Reading the documentation about token expiration didn't clarify it to me(I'm still a beginner).

Is there any way I could configure the 'timeToLive' to infinity or somehow prevent the token to expire ?

I only need to implement the client(in Java) so I do not have knowledge about how webservice works (it is in .NET).

Any explanation or link to a good tutorial is greatly appreciated.